# How to make an input range without snapping to tickmarks

Tags: html

Consider the code below that I copied from the [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range#adding_hash_marks):

```html
<label for="temp">Choose a comfortable temperature:</label><br />
<input type="range" id="temp" name="temp" list="tickmarks" />

<datalist id="tickmarks">
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="25"></option>
  <option value="50"></option>
  <option value="75"></option>
  <option value="100"></option>
</datalist>
```

As you can see the result is a nice looking range with tickmarks. However, when you try to select the value that is very close to the tickmark value, the range input will snap to that value when using a mouse-drag as input. One can use a workaround to use the keyboard to get those values, but this is not an intuitive or accessible one. This makes it in some cases impossible to select those values and is therefore not what I need since those values are valid options too.

Reading the documentation on those [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range#adding_hash_marks):

> The values provided are suggestions, not requirements: users can select from this predefined list or provide a different value.

Clearly I am experiencing something different here, at least for mouse-drag input that is. I have tried this code snippet on both Chrome and Firefox to rule out any browser implementation inconsistencies.

How can I add an input range with tickmarks while not including the snapping?

Comment: FYI, I tested on both Firefox and Chrome (Windows) and experienced minor snapping only on Chrome.

Comment: The width of the `<input>` may be a contributing factor. I tested by setting it to `width: 100%` and that eliminated the snapping on Chrome. In your case, a minimum width of 400px was required to eliminate snapping. Values less than 400px resulted in snapping.

Comment: I'd say this is expected behaviour. You could simply *not* use the tick-marks. If you want them purely for aesthetics, I guess currently you can't, unless the input has sufficient width, as mentioned before. You'd have to make the tick-marks yourself in any number of ways.